# Grep based on decimal places in two columns

Tags: r

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
x        y 
112.21   234.511
56.22    1.1111
3.456    2.31 
1.1      2.4567 
3.411    4.5
```

I want to subset the rows of this dataset by values of x and y which have 2 or more decimal places. So the end result will be this:

```
x        y 
112.21   234.511
56.22    1.1111
3.456    2.31 

# two last rows are removed as they have values with less than 2 decimal places
```

I tried doing something of this sort, but it doesn't work properly (it keeps some 1 decimal place values):

```
edited_df <- df[grep("\\.[1-9][1-9]", df$x) && grep("\\.[1-9][1-9]", df$y)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a tricky/undefined thing, because your numbers, if floating point, may be stored differently than what you see.  It is possible that you see one decimal place but perhaps internally it is have precision beyond the first decimal place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `d` is as in the Note the end, create a function `decimals` that returns TRUE for each element of its vector argument that has 2+ decimals (or FALSE otherwise) or if given a data frame argument applies that to each column.  Use it to subset `d`.

```
decimals <- function(x) sapply(x, grepl, pattern = r"{\.\d\d}")

subset(d, decimals(x) & decimals(y))
##         x        y
## 1 112.210 234.5110
## 2  56.220   1.1111
## 3   3.456   2.3100
```

or if there can be an unknown number of numeric columns in `d` or different column names then replace the last line with:

```
subset(d, apply(decimals(d), 1, all))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
x        y 
112.21   234.511
56.22    1.1111
3.456    2.31 
1.1      2.4567 
3.411    4.5"
d <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `nchar` on the "suffix" after the point, which you get using `gsub`.

```
d[rowSums(nchar(sapply(d, gsub, pa="^.*\\.", re="")) > 1) > 1, ]
#         x        y
# 1 112.210 234.5110
# 2  56.220   1.1111
# 3   3.456   2.3100
```

If `gsub` was `Vectorized` like so:

```
g <- Vectorize(gsub)
```

we could do the approach slightly more succinct:

```
d[rowSums(nchar(g(pa="^.*\\.", re="", d)) > 1) > 1, ]
#         x        y
# 1 112.210 234.5110
# 2  56.220   1.1111
# 3   3.456   2.3100
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(x = c(112.21, 56.22, 3.456, 1.1, 3.411), y = c(234.511, 
1.1111, 2.31, 2.4567, 4.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```